# How to remove dynamically added text-content and offer new text?

Tags: javascript, dom

In my HTML I want to place a word within the `id=“button__anfang“`

```
<p class="card-text" id="text__anfang"></p>
```

For this  I have an array with words to chose from. A function: `ausgabe_start` choses randomly a word and place it there by click on a button.

This is the function which places the randomly choosen word in the node with the `id "text-anfang"`.

```
let ausgabe_start = () => {
    arrWords.push(textAnfang.textContent = start[number_start]);
}
```

For some reason it pushes the word into another array. `[number_start]` is the index which takes a word from the `array start`. It is randomly.

**When I don't like the word, I want to click the button again, to get a new one. And I don't want a complete page reload**

How can I make the function chose again from the array and place the word within `id="text__anfang"`?

I tried a query within the function like in *pseudocode*:

```
If text__anfang.length != "0" delete text__anfang.
```

Pls. take a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Sven72/pen/XWJvrWZ)

Answer (score 0):

In the callback function for the click event listener you're actually pushing the assignment to `textAnfang.textContent` to the array **arrWords**.
The text itself is defined by the result of `start[number_start]);` where `start` is your array of words and `number_start` a random integer. If you want to have another random index, you need to give number_start another value inside the callback handler like:

```
let ausgabe_start = () => {
  let number_start = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2));
  textAnfang.textContent = start[number_start];
}
```

The drawback here is that it might return the self random word again because there is no check to make sure that it doesn't happen. You can workaround this by putting the assignment inside a do-while loop which repeates itself as long as the random word and the current value of **textAnfang** are equal.

```
let ausgabe_start = () => {
  let tempStr;
  do {
    number_start = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2));
    tempStr = start[number_start];
  }
  while (tempStr == textAnfang.textContent);
  textAnfang.textContent = tempStr;
}
```